# How to get code completion working for c++ in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: c++, sublimetext, sublimetext3, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Is it possible to get code completion working in Sublime Text 3 for C++? I tried the CTags plugin and I don't like that fact that it creates tag database in all directories. I work on a project that has a shared codebase and consists of a large number of sub-directories containing source files.

Comment: Were you able to get this working, by mine or another method? Please select and vote an answer if you were.

Answer (score 1):

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-3-sublimeclang-cygwin-mingw-64bit/16253

I just documented my config for c++ code completion. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation!